# Como fazer a minha imagem aparecer dentro da tag ui:repeat?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Tenho uma dúvida. Estou usando JSF e PrimeFaces para fazer um site para ebooks e preciso exibir os ebooks que estão armazenados no banco de dados. Consigo cadastrar o ebook normalmente, mas na hora de exibir, a imagem da capa do ebook não aparece. Fiz o mesmo exemplo usando um documento HTML simples e a imagem apareceu, só que no seguinte código não aparece:

```
<ui:repeat var="livro" value="#{livroBean.listaCompleta}">
        <p:fieldset legend="#{livro.titulo}" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:graphicImage value="#{livro.urlCapa}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{livro.sinopse}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente

```
<ui:repeat value="#{livroBean.listaCompleta}" var="livro">
    <p:fieldset legend="#{livro.titulo}" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:graphicImage value="#{livro.urlCapa}">
                <h:outputText value="#{livro.sinopse}" />
                </h:outputText>
                </h:graphicImage>
            </h:panelGrid>
   </p:fieldset>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Testei e não deu certo =\ mas obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim.